# Minimizing error for $A$ in $Ax=b$ if $x$ and $b$ are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

There was an answer give for how to solve $Ax=b$ if $x$ and $b$ are known here:

[Solving for $A$ in $Ax = b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778421/solving-for-a-in-ax-b)

But I was wondering is there a way to solve it if there is no exact solution and you want to minimize error, similar to how you solve $Ax=b$ for $x$ if using least squares if there is no exact solution.

Additionally, say $X$ and $B$ are matrices that correspond to a bunch of $Ax=b$ equations. Are there known methods for minimizing error in that case?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Solving for $A$ in $Ax=b$ is not possible in general, is it?

Comment: $A\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=b$ only says that the first column of $A$ is $b$, nothing else

Comment: I don't think so but finding a solution with some error criteria is probably possible

Comment: What you mean? Take my example once again, you can only determine that $A = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & * \\ b_2 & * \end{pmatrix}$, where $*$ are *arbitrary* constants. What do you mean for "some error criteria"?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question in my opinion. It is a baby step towards the low-rank Hessian update formulas that are used in quasi-Newton methods (SR1, DFP, etc).

Here is one way to go about it:

First, let us frame it as the following optimization problem:
$$\boxed{\min_A \frac{1}{2}\|AX - B\|_\text{Fro}^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|A\|_\text{Fro}^2}$$
where $\|\cdot\|_\text{Fro}$ is the Frobenius matrix norm (square root of the sum of squares of all matrix entries), and $\alpha$ is a regularization parameter.

It is straightforward to see that $\|M\|_\text{Fro}^2 = \operatorname{trace}\left[M^TM\right]$, where $\operatorname{trace}\left[\cdot\right]$ is the matrix trace (sum of all diagonal entries). Thus the objective function may be written as
$$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{trace}\left[\left(AX - B\right)^T\left(AX - B\right)\right] + \frac{\alpha}{2}\operatorname{trace}\left[A^TA\right].$$
The solution to the optimization problem is the matrix $A$ such that the derivative of the objective function is zero if $A$ is perturbed in any direction $H$. Using the linearity and cyclic properties of the trace, we have
\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{d}{dA}\left(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{trace}\left[\left(AX - B\right)^T\left(AX - B\right)\right] + \frac{\alpha}{2}\operatorname{trace}\left[A^TA\right]\right) \cdot H \\
&= \operatorname{trace}\left[\left(HX\right)^T\left(AX - B\right)\right]+\alpha \operatorname{trace}\left[H^TA\right]  \\
&= \operatorname{trace}\left[H^T\left(\left(AX - B\right)X^T + \alpha A\right)\right]
\end{align*}
Since this must hold for all perturbations $H$, we must have
$$0 = \left(AX - B\right)X^T + \alpha A$$
or
$$A\left(XX^T + \alpha I\right) = BX^T$$
which is a linear system that you may solve to find
$$\boxed{A = BX^T\left(XX^T + \alpha I\right)^{-1}}$$

What's more, using the [Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) we have
$$\left(XX^T + \alpha I\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\left( I - X\left(\alpha I + X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T\right)$$
and therefore
$$\boxed{A = \frac{1}{\alpha}BX^T - \frac{1}{\alpha}BX^T X\left(\alpha I + X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T .}$$

### Code:

Here is some python/numpy code that tests the formula:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
r = 3

X = np.random.randn(N,r)
B = np.random.randn(N,r)

a = 1e-6
print('a=', a)
A = (1./a) * B @ X.T @ (np.eye(N) - X @ np.linalg.inv(a*np.eye(r) + X.T @ X) @ X.T)

rel_res = np.linalg.norm(A @ X - B) / np.linalg.norm(B)
print('rel_res=', rel_res)

norm_A = np.linalg.norm(A)
print('norm_A=', norm_A)
```

and here is the output of running that code:

```
a= 1e-06
rel_res= 2.3549592377658484e-07
norm_A= 2.24920744100694
```

### Special cases:

The optimization problem simultaneously tries to make $AX=B$, and tries to make $A$ small. The regularization parameter, $\alpha$, regulates the tradeoff between these competing goals. In the limit as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, satisfying the constraint $AX=B$ is prioritized over making $A$ small. In this limit, we have
$$X^T\left(XX^T + \alpha I\right)^{-1} \underset{\alpha \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} X^+$$
where $X^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $X$, and so
$$A \underset{\alpha \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} B X^+.$$

- In the over-determined special case, $A=BX^+$ is the minimizer of $\frac{1}{2}\|AX-B\|_\text{Fro}^2$ without any regularization.
- In the underdetermined special case, $A=BX^+$ is the minimizer of $\frac{1}{2}\|A\|^2$ subject to the constraint that $AX=B$.
- If $XX^T$ is invertible, then $X^+=X^T(XX^T)^{-1}$.
- If $X^TX$ is invertible, then $X^+=(X^TX)^{-1}X$.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the answer. It is going to take me while to digest this.