# Finding matrix least square problem

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, solution-verification

If you have a function of the form

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert Ax - y \right\rVert_2^2
$$

We know that if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can find the minimizer by differentiating

$$
\nabla_x f = A^TAx - A^Ty
$$

setting this to $0$ leads to the linear system

$$
A^TAx = A^Ty.
$$

Suppose now instead of $x$ being unknown the unknown is $A$. In this case we have

$$
f(A) = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Ax - y \right\rVert_2^2
$$

To calculate the gradient w.r.t. $A$ I proceed as follows (assuming as a norm for $A$ I am using the 2 norm).

$$
\lim_{E \to 0} \frac{\left| f(A + E) - f(A) - T(A)E \right|}{\left\lVert E \right\rVert_2}
$$

With a little bit of calculation we can show that
$$
f(A + E) - f(A) =  \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)Ex +\left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2
$$

Substituing this into the limit and using the squeeze theorem I get

$$
0 \leq \lim_{E \to 0} \frac{\left| \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)Ex +\left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2 - T(A)E \right|}{\left\lVert E \right\rVert_2} \leq \lim_{E \to 0} \frac{\left| \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)Ex  - T(A)E \right| +\left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2 }{\left\lVert E \right\rVert_2} \leq \lim_{E \to 0} \frac{\left\lVert \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)(\cdot)x  - T(A) \right\rVert_{{\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}}^*} \left\lVert E \right\rVert_2 +\left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2 }{\left\lVert E \right\rVert_2} = \lim_{E \to 0} \left\lVert \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)(\cdot)x  - T(A) \right\rVert_{{\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}}^*}
$$

The last limit is equal to 0 iff
$$
T(A) = \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)(\cdot)x
$$

**Question** 1: Is my calculation of the differential correct? Assuming it is I was trying to characterize $T(A)$ using a basis $E_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ by doing this I get

$$
T(A)E_{ij} = \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)E_{ij}x = \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right)x_j e_i = x_j \left(x^TA^T - y^T\right) e_i = x_j \left(x^TA^T e_i  - y^T e_i \right) = x_j \left(x^TA^T  e_i  - y_i \right)
$$

**Question 2**: Is this correct? This should give me a set of equations that I should be able to solve for $A$?

Comment: There is a bag of tricks that lets you manipulate optimization problems where the unknown is a matrix. The first trick is to write the norm in terms of traces, and then use the cyclic permutation properties of traces. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra) The second trick is to use vectorization and Kronecker products https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Comment: I'll have a look, but I do prefer the use of definition if differential because is more general.

Comment: But it's a least square problem. Assuming convexity shouldn't the solution be unique?

Comment: Ok no problem. Do you know a better way to characterize the problem maybe? I have, from a paper, a problem of the form $$\frac{1}{2}\left\lVert XA - B \right\rVert_F^2 $$ (assuming $X,A,B$ have compatible dimensions). I need to find $X$ given $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I think that $A$ has minimum norm is a good criterion but I don't know how to impose that.

Comment: @NickAlger it would be useful to know how can I write the norms in terms of traces. Can you point maybe where in the link I can find such a trick? I also see references to Frobenious norm which is not mentioned in my question (I am assuming $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_2$).

Comment: @user8469759 We have $||Ax-y||_2^2 = ||Ax-y||_\text{Fro}^2$ because the Frobenius norm and induced 2-norm are the same on vectors (they only differ once you go to matrices). Then we have $||Ax-y||_\text{Fro}^2=\text{trace}\left[(Ax-y)^T(Ax-y)\right]$ since $||X||_\text{Fro}^2 = \text{trace}\left[X^T X\right]$ for any matrix $X$, including the special case where the ``matrix'' $X$ is a $N \times 1$ column vector.

Comment: Here is a related question from a while ago that may be useful to look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4459228/3060